# R ggplot multivariable facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have df USArrests, that contains 3 crime statistics per US State and an additional UrbanPop variable. I'm trying to create faceted bar chart(s) that contain the 3 crime statistics of each state, with the y-axis being cases per 100,000 people at specific breaks (100, 200, 300). The top of the graph would read the state that it is from.

My main issue is that i'm just not fully understanding the mapping/aes function and how that relates into pulling all 3 variables together in one graph. Thanks

```
library(ggplot2)

USArrests$state_name <- rownames(USArrests)

p <- ggplot() +
  layer(data = USArrests,
        stat = "identity",
        geom = "bar",
        mapping = aes(x = Assault, Rape, Murder),
          position = "identity") +
  scale_y_discrete(name = "Cases per 100,000 people",
                     breaks = c(100, 200, 300),
                     labels = c("100", "200", "300")) +
           facet_wrap(~ state_name)
plot(p)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to reshape your data frame. `USArrests2` is the reshaped data frame. After that, you can plot the `Crime` as category on the x axis and `Number` as continuous on the y-axis. In this case, you can also use `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`. They are the same. `facet_wrap` is the way to generate facets. You can use `ncol` or `nrow` to specify the column or row numbers.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

USArrests2 <- USArrests %>%
  gather(Crime, Number, Assault, Rape, Murder)

ggplot(USArrests2, aes(x = Crime, y = Number)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(100, 200, 300)) +
  facet_wrap(~ state_name, nrow = 5)
```

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful